# Catching strings for output

Tags: c++, string, try-catch

I have a try catch statement in my main function

```
try
{
    app.init();
}
catch(std::string errorMessage)
{
    std::cout << errorMessage;
    return 1;
}
```

but when I `throw "SOME_ERROR";` The console output is simply

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'char const*'
Aborted (core dumped)
```

How can I make errorMessage output to the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either intend to throw `std::string` OR catch `const char*`:

```
throw std::string("error")

catch(const char* message)
```

However as pointed out, it's better just to derive from `std::exception`:

```
#include <iostream>
// must include these
#include <exception> 
#include <stdexcept>

struct CustomException : std::exception {
  const char* what() const noexcept {return "Something happened!\n";}
};

int main () {
  try {
      // throw CustomException();
      // or use one already provided

      throw std::runtime_error("You can't do that, buddy.");
  } catch (std::exception& ex) {
      std::cout << ex.what();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Catching a const char* got the output I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Seriously use strings @Mike and use exceptions for the destructor. You don't want strings, you want exceptions - having a string representation is good! But not if you actually want to use exceptions for actual programming reasons (rather than just output).

Comment: @AlecTeal Really the only thing I'm using this for is to get some text regarding why the program crashed into the console for debugging simple issues. What benefits would I get from using exceptions?

Comment: @Mike memory safety - which is VERY important- and the string you'd see comes from the call to what(), so you'd also get an error message, you'll see something like "Caught MyEceptionOrWhatever with (message from what)"

Comment: Upvote for being right and adding the bit about exceptions *grumbles something* :P

Comment: I suppose I'll do it simply for the habit of it, I think it's a bit much for what I'm trying to do at the moment but eventually I'll need to so might as well get some practice in now.

Comment: @Mike if you are DEBUGGING - without using a debugger - which isn't hard to use (YOU CAN CLICK DEBUG IN ECLIPSE AND GET A NICE INTERFACE!!!!) you should not be doing this. You should learn what the debugger is, why it is your best friend and use exceptions properly.

Answer (score 2):

Please do not throw anything which is not derived from std::exception.

An exemption might be an exception intended to terminate the program (providing an internal state, though)

Comment: Another upvote, for being right. Does no one appreciate mine!

Answer (score 1):

You need to derive something from std::exception. `<--if you want memory safety`

It has a method: `virtual const char* ::std::exception::what() const noexcept;`

Build your char* you want to see in the constructor, store it, return it for what() then free it in the destructor for memory safe exceptions.